# solving inside for loop and sorting x which are less than 3 and greater than -3 from the list

Tags: differential-equations, filtering, conditional

I give a simple function code here...

```
Clear[a, x, t]; 
s = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] + a*x[t] == 0, x[0]==1}, x, {t, 0, 100}, {a}] 
y = x[1] /. s
y[5] /. s
```

I tabulated the solution in a list..

```
r = Table[y[a] /. s, {a, 0, 15}]
```

Then I used `Select` to select

```
st = Select[r, -3 < # < 1 &]
```

Now i tried to print required $x$ with their corresponding $a$, but I could not do this.

How could I do this, And their may be a case in which their are repeated x value for common a, how to identify that.`Print[s, "      ", a]`

For reference I attach the pic of my code and result...[image: code and the result]

Comment: Why not tell `Solve[]` at the outset your constraints on the solution? `Table[x /. Solve[x^2 - a^2 == 0 && -3 < x < 3, x], {a, 1, 14}]`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it does not work with ParametricNDSolve or other functions. Actually I wnt to do this logic for a and q parameters of Mathieu equation, without using inbuilt Mathieu functions.

Comment: Then you *oversimplified* your problem; maybe come up with a more representative, yet still sufficiently simple example?